# Time-lagged cross correlation between two measurements across multiple people

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, lags

I have collected time-series data from a few hundred people. For each person, I have two measurements that I am interested in correlating.
Specifically, I want to identify the time point at which those two measurements are most strongly correlated.

I *think* what I want is a time-lagged cross correlation (although I am open to other suggestions here).

However, from what I can find, TLCC only look at the correlation between two columns of data-in my example, this would be data from a single person. I presume I would need to repeat this analysis hundreds of times and then look at an average or something...I'm not really sure.

How can I do this analysis across hundreds of people? Is there another analysis I should consider?

I suppose I could rephrase my research question to be something like:
"On average across all participants, what is the time lag at which two measurements are most strongly correlated?"